# Why firing a defined event with dispatchEvent doesn't obey the bubbling behavior of events?

Tags: javascript, events, event-bubbling, dispatchevent

I'm confused with the script below:

```
var event = new Event('shazam');

document.body.addEventListener('shazam',function(){
    alert('body');
});

document.addEventListener('shazam',function(){
    alert('document');
});

window.addEventListener('shazam',function(){
    alert('window');
});

document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

When I run this script on my browser, I just get the ***alert('body');*** event.
but if i set the capturing parameter of addEventListener (the third optional parameter) to true, all the alerts captured in order they should.

Why the ***shazam event*** doesn't bubble up ?

Comment: Create a `CustomEvent` instead of `Event` and pass it `true` as the second parameter (the canBubble parameter)

Comment: the property seems to not called 'canBubble', it is 'bubbles'.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to set the `bubbles` property to true, and you have to do this during the construction:

```js
var event = new Event('shazam', { bubbles: true });
```

or the old way with `initEvent`, passing true as the second argument to allow bubble:

```js
event.initEvent('shazam', true);
```

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Thank you for your brief response :)

Comment: But one question:
why bubbling is by default disabled in Event Object.

Comment: It defaults to false as per https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event (or, if you prefer, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event ). I would guess this is to provide the option with the least potential side effects by default.