# Nested web-components and event handling

Tags: javascript, web-component, dom-events, custom-element

I'm writing a memory game in javascript. I have made a web-component for the cards, `<memory-card>` and a web-component to contain the cards and handle the game state `<memory-game>`. The `<memory-card>` class contains its image path for when its turned over, the default image to display as the back of the card, its turned state and an `onclick` function to handle switching between the states and the images.

The `<memory-game>` class has a setter that receives an array of images to generate `<memory-cards>` from. What would be the best method to handle updating the game state in the `<memory-game>` class? Should I attach an additional event listener to the `<memory-card>` elements there or is there a better way to solve it? I would like the `<memory-card>` elements to only handle their own functionality as they do now, ie changing images depending on state when clicked.

**memory-game.js**

```
class memoryGame extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    this.cards = []
    this.turnedCards = 0
  }

  flipCard () {
    if (this.turnedCards < 2) {
      this.turnedCards++
    } else {
      this.turnedCards = 0
      this.cards.forEach(card => {
        card.flipCard(true)
      })
    }
  }

  set images (paths) {
    paths.forEach(path => {
      const card = document.createElement('memory-card')
      card.image = path
      this.cards.push(card)
    })
  }

  connectedCallback () {
    this.cards.forEach(card => {
      this.root.append(card)
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('memory-game', memoryGame)
```

**memory-card.js**

```
class memoryCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    // set default states
    this.turned = false
    this.path = 'image/0.png'
    this.root.innerHTML = `<img src="${this.path}"/>`
    this.img = this.root.querySelector('img')
  }

  set image (path) {
    this.path = path
  }

  flipCard (turnToBack = false) {
    if (this.turned || turnToBack) {
      this.turned = false
      this.img.setAttribute('src', 'image/0.png')
    } else {
      this.turned = true
      this.img.setAttribute('src', this.path)
    }    
  }

  connectedCallback () {
    this.addEventListener('click', this.flipCard())
  }
}

customElements.define('memory-card', memoryCard)
```

**implementing the custom event after Supersharp's answer**

**memory-card.js (extract)**

```
connectedCallback () {
    this.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.flipCard()
      const event = new CustomEvent('flippedCard')
      this.dispatchEvent(event)
    })
  }
```

**memory-game.js (extract)**

```
  set images (paths) {
    paths.forEach(path => {
      const card = document.createElement('memory-card')
      card.addEventListener('flippedCard', this.flipCard.bind(this))
      card.image = path
      this.cards.push(card)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Yes and no. ....

Comment: This is broad, provide the codes you have tried.

Comment: I'd do something like this: create a `handleCardFlip(cardNumber, isOpen)` method on the "game controller" (or whatever you have). `bind` this method to the game controller. Pass this method ot cards when you create them. Call this method from inside cards.

Comment: @Aria I'm trying to make this a broad best practice question, I don't have access to my code at the moment but I'm not necessarily looking for a code answer either I want to know how I should think about handling events in nested web-components, the answer should be applicable to any scenario where you want a web component to respond to changes in one of its nested components.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you, that sounds sensible, I will try this approach when I get home

Comment: @ChristopherKarlsson You may look this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001211/how-to-communicate-between-web-components-native-ui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `<memory-card>`:

- Create with `CustomEvent()` and dispatch a custom event with `dispatchEvent()`

In the `<memory-game>`:

- Listen to your custom event with `addEventListener()`

Because the cards are nested in the game, the event will bubble naturally to the container.

This way the 2 custom elements will stay loosley coupled.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to implement the solution in this answer.

Comment: My implementation:
**In memory-card.js i added**
const event = new CustomEvent('flippedCard')
      this.dispatchEvent(event)
to the pre-existing click eventlistener
**in memory-game.js i added**
card.addEventListener('flippedCard', this.flipCard.bind(this))
to set images after creating the memory-card element

Comment: You could also use the arrow notation to avoir `bind()`: `() => this.flipCard()`

Answer (score 2):

Supersharps answer is not 100% correct.

`click` events bubble up the DOM, 
but CustomEvents (inside shadowDOM) **do not**

[Why firing a defined event with dispatchEvent doesn't obey the bubbling behavior of events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048322/why-firing-a-defined-event-with-dispatchevent-doesnt-obey-the-bubbling-behavior)

So you have to add the `bubbles:true` yourself:

```
[yoursender].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent([youreventName], {
                                                  bubbles: true,
                                                  detail: [yourdata]
                                                }));
```

more: https://javascript.info/dispatch-events

note: `detail` can be a function: [How to communicate between Web Components (native UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001211/how-to-communicate-between-web-components-native-ui/55059157#55059157)

#### For an Eventbased programming challenge

```
   this.cards.forEach(card => {
    card.flipCard(true)
  })
```

First of all that `this.cards` is not required, as all cards are available in `[...this.children]`

!! Remember, in JavaScript Objects are passed by reference, so your `this.cards` is pointing to the exact **same** DOM children

You have a dependency here,
the Game needs to know about the `.flipCard` method in Card.

► Make your Memory Game send ONE Event which is received by EVERY card

hint: every card needs to 'listen' at Game DOM level to receive a bubbling Event

in my code that whole loop is:

`game.emit('allCards','close');`

Cards are responsible to listen for the correct EventListener
(attached to `card.parentNode`)

That way it does not matter how many (or What ever) cards there are in your game

#### The DOM is your data-structure

If your Game no longer cares about how many or what DOM children it has,
and it doesn't do any bookkeeping of elements it already has,
shuffling becomes a piece of cake:

```
  shuffle() {
    console.log('► Shuffle DOM children');
    let game = this,
        cards = [...game.children],//create Array from a NodeList
        idx = cards.length;
    while (idx--) game.insertBefore(rand(cards), rand(cards));//swap 2 random DOM elements
  }
```

My global rand function, producing a random value from an Array OR a number

```
  rand = x => Array.isArray(x) ? x[rand(x.length)] : 0 | x * Math.random(),
```

#### Extra challenge

If you get your Event based programming right,
then creating a Memory Game with **three matching cards** is another piece of cake

.. or 4 ... or N matching cards

Answer (score 1):

It would be *very* helpful to see some of your existing code to know what you have tried. But without it you ca do what @Supersharp has proposed, or you can have the `<memory-game>` class handle all events.

If you go this way then your code for `<memory-card>` would listen for `click` events on the entire field. It would check to see if you clicked on a card that is still face down and, if so, tell the card to flip. (Either through setting a property or an attribute, or through calling a function on the `<memory-card>` element.)

All of the rest of the logic would exist in the `<memory-game>` class to determine if the two selected cards are the same and assign points, etc.

If you want the cards to handle the `click` event then you would have that code generate a new `CustomEvent` to indicate that the card had flipped. Probably including the coordinates of the card within the grid and the type of card that is being flipped.

The `<memory-game>` class would then listen for the `flipped` event and act upon that information.

However you do this isn't really a problem. It is just how you want to code it and how tied together you want the code. If you never plan to use this code in any other games, then it does not matter as much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Intervalia it further explains the logic suggested by @Supersharp and was very helpful. I added my code to my question in case you have a suggestion for a better implementation.