# Use document in custom element (web component)

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I have two separate custom element components and if I want to do something with the ComponentB's element inside of ComponentA, what is the best way to do it?

**index.html**

```
<body>

  <componentA>
    <div class="container">
     <p>I am component A</p>
     <p>abc</p>
    </div>
  </componentA>

  <componentB>
    <div class="container">
     <p>I am component B</p>
     <p></p> // Will set data between the p tag in componentA
    </div>
  </componentB>

</body>
```

**componentA.js**

```
...component template...

class ComponentA extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    this.setInnerTextToComponentBElement();

  }

  setInnerTextToComponentBElement(){

    // How to set componentB's second p tag innerText?

  }
}

customElements.define('componentA', ComponentA );
```

I have thought of using document.querySelector to get the componentB element and go from there... but is this the best practice way to do it?

Comment: Events, like you asked for in your previous question. Note: You can pass anything in ``event.detail``, doesn't have to be data. So **A** can pass a _**A-method**_ **reference** to **B** in an Event, then **B** can execute it

Comment: Hi, thanks Danny, so basically what you mean is I need to dispatch the custom event to the parent(in this case is the normal DOM) and inside of componentB I'll need to catch the event using document.addEventListener()? and another small question is that is it consider bad practice to interact with other web component siblings? thanks

Comment: Or make event listeners listen at document or a common parent level. You have many options. There are no bad practices, software development is art. You are the artist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest NEVER tying two components together without allowing the developer using the components to provide a way to connect them.

Normally communications or interconnections between elements is handled by the parent. The only element that I know of that does this by itself is the `<label>` element. If this is the parent of an `<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>` or `<textarea>` then it will pass its focus on to the child element.

But to use it with a sibling element you have to set the `for` attribute of the `<label>` to be the `id` of the other field. And then the other field needs to have its `id` set.

I answered something like this here:
[How to communicate between Web Components (native UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001211/how-to-communicate-between-web-components-native-ui/55027467#55027467)

Once you tie two components together these components are no longer usable by themselves unless you write extra code to allow separation.

Instead, either allow the components to dispatch events that the parent will receive and the parent will then pass values on to the other component. Or, follow the example of how `<label for="">` works.

Comment: Hi, so for using the dispatch events way, you mean like inside of componentA I dispatch an custom event to the actual parent document(not the #document-fragment) and listen to the custom event inside of the componentB?

Comment: Yes. Try to keep your custom components functioning the same way that built in components work. Besides the `<label>` component, all components only communicate through events going up to their parents. The `<from>`, `<audio>` and `<video>` are minor exceptions since they do use their children. Like a `<form>` will gather the data from all of the child input elements and pass that data on to the server. `<audio>` and `<video>` use child elements to provide source data. But no built in elements talk directly to a sibling. `<label>` sets focus on the element defined in the `for` attribute.

Comment: To be fair. The elements with shadow DOM will normally dispatch their custom events using `this.dispatchEvent` so it is sent from the element container and not from a sub element in the shadow-dom. Although if you embed other elements in your shadow DOM then those will/should dispatch on their element container, etc.

Comment: What about can I use "document.querySelector()" to pass data to another sibling web component's property? does this count as talking to sibling directly? example: Two web component /custom element inside of the normal document(not the #document-fragment) and inside of componentA, I use document.querySelector('componentB').myData = 'random data'; to pass data to componentB.  thanks

Comment: Sure, You CAN do that, but should you? If you tie two components together by using a query selector then the two components ALWAYS need to be together. Now if you don't expect these components to ever be used alone or if they will never leave this page, go for it. But if you want reusability, then I suggest against it. Instead do something like the `<label>` attribute `for`. This allows the component to work even if the second component isn't there. Since it would have have a `for` value it would do nothing. With the `for` value it would then be told what component it will communicate with.